# Kernel update won't allow Nvidia 1660 drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 - how do I fix?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 22.04

Ran basic kernel update via built-in updates this morning.

Now my NVidia 1660 is not recognized.

Tried to install nvidia drivers again using:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

That fails with erros which look like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
```

Now, the graphics show up like:

llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)

Only 1 of my 2 monitors works and my display is at 1024x768.

Have no idea what to do.

**Update**

I just found this but it seems to be a false positive.
[image: nvidia 1660 driver]

I attempted to run the NVidia provided .run file to install and saw this:

I believe the important part is :

> ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running
> kernel.

[image: kernel source]

Then i tried switching in the panel and saw this:

[image: error kernel]

This must be happening to someone else, also, right?

I have installed the kernel headers in an attempt to get the NVidia drivers to work:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

I'm now downloading Ubuntu 22.04 iso, imaging a USB stick and going to see if I can repair the installation.

So there is no "repair" option but when I run the USB stick version I get both monitors back and at a valid (high) resolution.

This is ridiculous.  All because I accepted a kernel update from the official updates.  Oy!

**Definitive Answer**

I had to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS again.  I was *very* lucky because I had just done a complete backup of my system yesterday. Phew...Very lucky.

**Beware!**

I've always immediately installed kernel updates.  I will now wait to install them if I am able.

**Restore Previous Kernel**

I also attempted to restore the previous kernel.
Here is a snapshot of the choices I had:

[image: GRUB kernel list]

I tried each one, but none of them got me back to a good place.
Even after trying each one I still only had 1 screen & it was stuck at 1024x768.

**2022-10-26**
I just started my computer up & it is back to 1 screen & 1024x768.
I really dislike Ubuntu now.  Would this happen on Mint?

Comment: Did you remove and purge the Nvida driver you already have installed first? To update or change or reinstall the nvidia driver you need to remove any that may be there first.

Comment: I went back and tried uninstalling it first and then I installed it again and it still fails.  Actually, I was able to install with the following command `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520-open` which according to `ubuntu-drivers devices` is supposed to be the correct driver but I still have only 1 screen & 1024x768 and not nvidia drivers.

Comment: Have you tried to boot your computer with a previous kernel version? You can do that by going into the GRUB menu at boot and then select a previous version. Background for my comment: I also had a kernel and nvidia update today, which totally messed up my computer. There must be something wrong with the kernel that got installed on my computer. However, when booting into GRUB and using the last-known-good kernel version I can use the computer without problems.

Comment: I will definitely try what you are saying, but I don't know how.  I will look it up.  If you see this I appreciate a link to askubuntu that explains how to boot from last-known-good kernel.  Thanks

Comment: I tried the 3 different versions of the kernel listed & none of them worked.  OY!!! I'm leaving Ubuntu & heading for MINT since I have to rebuild my machine to get this to work anyways.  I really cannot believe that a kernel version was pushed that basically destroyed my ability to run Ubuntu with my nvidia card.  Been working on this for 3 hours.  What a waste of time.

Comment: The 520-open is still a work in progress, not recommended for commercial GPUs yet.  Latest Nvidia driver installs seem to remove completely previous drivers, so older kernels have no driver but the nouveau. The good news is the mok business allows secure boot to be on transparently -- I never noticed through kernel/video driver updates for several months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started up my computer today & I had the same issue again.
It was terrible.  Only 1 screen & 1024x768 resolution.

I went into upgrade settings and found the additional drivers tab and chose the following driver:

[image: nvidia 1660 driver]

This is the one you have to choose if you're running the NVidia 1660 graphics card.   This fixed the issue.
I can't believe it is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the exact same probelm after updating my ubuntu kernel.

My system details:
**Linux ubuntu-linux 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

The key here is to just remove the new kernel and then remove all the nvidia-drivers associated with that kernel in the system.

Command for removing the kernel.
`sudo apt remove linux-*5.17*`

As we have removed the kernel, restart the system. Now we'll be fixing the traceback error which we get when we are getting while running `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`

This problem is occuring as there's a recent change in version formatting naming in the nvidia drivers.

The script which we are going to edit is found in the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers`.
Inside this just change this 
`version = int(package_name.split('-')[-1])` to
`version = int(package_name.split('-')[2])`.

Now if you try to run the command:
`sudo ubuntu-drivers install`

It'll be fixed and be running again, which will configure the nvidia drivers for you automatically.

If after running you find that you have got nouveau drivers installed instead of nvidia you can simply open the `Additional drivers` application and select the nvidia driver and install it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, and it worked for me as well as raddevus says with installing the 470 driver, however I first had to remove all Nvidia drivers with `sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` then selecting the 470 from the additional drivers and reboot.