# Ubuntu no longer boots after reinstalling graphics driver

Tags: boot, nvidia

Ubuntu-Version: 22.04 or 22.10, can't check anymore

I started my machine today and discovered that the desktop environment wasn't loaded.
I got some text which seemed to indicate ubuntu services starting, then it disappeared and I had a black screen with a blinking cursor. I was able to switch to a terminal with ctrl+alt+f3. After some googling and some digging around I ran `sudo lshw -c video` and saw the word unclaimed next to my graphics card, which I understood as the graphics driver not working.
So I did a `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and picked the recommended driver, which was as I recall nvidia-driver-520-open. So I tried to install it with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-520-open`. It reported that all drivers were already installed.
So I figured I could reinstall with apt: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-driver-520-open` (I think, I'm writing this from memory).
Then I rebooted, and got the same again. After some more googling, I find a post suggesting I need to install the linux-headers for the kernel version
So I did `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.17.0-1020-oem`(again - version from memory) and rebooted again.
And this time I got the gnome login screen and was able to log in. However I found in the ubuntu settings that the selected grahics card? was llvmpipe. So I tried selecting the nvidia graphics card using `sudo prime-select nvidia` and rebooted again. This changed nothing. So I thought I might have to try a different version of the driver.
I went to "Software & Updates" > "Additional drivers" and selected the 515 version of the driver. After the installation was finished I rebooted.
However now I can no longer really boot. I get some text which I assume to be kernel logs, then I get a black screen with the cursor again, but this time I cannot switch to a terminal. After retrying several times, I got gnome again, but the screen turned black a few seconds after logging in and it went unresponsive.

I am able to boot from the usb drive I used to install ubuntu

I realise that I've probably been an idiot here, but is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I suffered this problem yesterday and posted : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix
It's really quite terrible and I had to do a complete install to fix it also.

Comment: @raddevus yeah, that looks like the same problem, unfortunately I don't have a backup ready to go. I'll try Hannu's answer, but I'm afraid it's going to be a reinstall for me too.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot, as the "BIOS" text appears, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> **once**
   *(If that does not work, try holding down either <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key)*
2. ... that should make the "grub menu" appear.
3. Under the "Advanced" option, find "Recovery mode" for your latest kernel version and select it.
4. Yet another menu should appear; select options `fsck`, `enable networking` and then `drop to root prompt`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to actually get to the `#` prompt - i.e. Bash as user `root`.
5. Here you may do many things freely, i.e. destroy your Linux - so be thorough with what you type.
6. `dpkg --list | grep ^ii.*nvidia` will tell which nvidia related packages are installed.
7. do `sudo apt purge package-name` on all of it,
8. then do `reboot` and see if you can log in normally...
9. **If yes;** hit Super-key (Win-Key) and start typing `Additional drivers`, quite soon a greenish icon will appear; click on it / select it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Install an older nVidia driver and see if that works (I'm using 470)
10. **if no;** get back to the recovery mode root prompt and attempt to install e.g. version 470 of nvidia-drivers from there... type `apt install nvidia` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> at that point; a list of available drivers should appear; type the first char of one and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> again... then with the full name, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to attempt install.
    *(keep an eye on if there are any errors while installing! Try to revert such an installation with "purge" above)*

Comment: thank you for the help! I'll backup my home directory using the usb boot first though before I try anything else...

Comment: Consider this a first step (sequence) to attempt, there might be bigger problems behind though. Keep eyes open for errors.

Comment: I have been unable to enter the grub menu, neither the esc key, nor holding down the shift key did anything, probably going to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: I had the same issues as OP after updating to 525 today. I had to purge all nvidia packages as you described and then install both nvidia-driver-525 and nvidia-dkms-525 for it to work again.