# Gave up waiting for root file system device, after reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

context: this question: [Ubuntu no longer boots after reinstalling graphics driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437323/ubuntu-no-longer-boots-after-reinstalling-graphics-driver/1437331?noredirect=1#comment2506348_1437331)

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 according to these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation
I picked the same partition that my old broken installation was on, set the mount point to / and did not check format.

The installation finished without and error and then I tried to boot, but got the following error:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=<uuid> does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

After this the screen is unresponsive (I cannot enter commands here.)

After some googling I found that I should press `e` in the menu where I can choose between `Ubuntu` and `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and check whether the two UUIDs mentioned there are the same (which they are).

I did notice that when I go to Advanced option and pick `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.17.0-1020-oem` I get the aforementioned error, but if I pick `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic` it boots normally, I can log, get the gnome desktop, can access the file system etc...

Once I was logged in I did a `sudo grub-update`, which didn't seem to change anything.

Addressing the common problems in the error message (everything done booting with linux 5.15, if that matters):
`cat /proc/cmdline` returns `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0.52-generic root=<uuid> ro quiet splash` where  is the same uuid as in the error message, no mention of a rootdelay.

`cat /proc/modules` returns a lot of values, that I don't understand, don't know how I would find out what is missing?

`ls /dev` also return a lot of output, but again I don't know how I would know something is missing.

Anyone able to help out here?

Comment: The 5.17 oem is a problematic kernel and you should be using the 5.15

Comment: @David thanks, I'll probably do that, could you tell my why 5.17 oem is a problematic kernel?

Comment: Only that it does not work and when it does not all hardware is supported. Helped a user the other day that Bluetooth would not work with 5.17oem but all is good with 5.15

Comment: @HBnet where do you press `e` to choose? I have the same problem and I can't find it.

Comment: You don't need to press e to choose. You will have to enter the grub menu. It's been a while but I believe you need to press or hold Esc during boot to get there. You should be able to select a kernel version under the Advanced Options

Answer (score 1):

Is that kernel version "5.17.0-1020-oem" what you intended to install?
If you don't need that version, you can remove it from your environment.
I think you should use kernel version "5.15.0.52-generic".

- check kernel versions installed on your environment
  $ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
- remove unnecessary version
  $ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.17.0-1020-oem
- check kernel versions again (confirm that kernel version was removed)
  $ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
- update grub
  $ sudo update-grub

Comment: I never explicitly installed any kernel version. But my solution has been so far to just set 5.15 as the default