# 22.04.1 NVIDIA Drivers suddenly stopped working

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

**Specs:**

- Lenovo L340 Gaming Laptop
- CPU: Intel core i7-9750H
- GPU: Intel iGPU + NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1650
- NVIDIA DRIVER Version 520 open
- **Secure boot is ON and I don't want to disable it.**

Recently, a driver update made my secondary monitor non functioning, I tried removing and reinstalling the drivers, using both terminal and Ubuntu's Software Updater tool but it didn't solve anything, I believe the issue is somehow related to the signature of the drivers since it's not working.

I've ran the following commands and the results are as shown

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I've searched through the internet and found out there is some issue regarding the latest shipped NVIDIA driver, since many people have some sort of problem,

Also a side question, Is there any GUI Utility to help managing signed drivers, and for creating, modifying or deleting keys and signatures and stuff, since doing this on terminal is a very cumbersome and I barely have time and want to be able to fix similar issue faster in the future.

Comment: I experienced this yesterday and posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix
It offers some ways to attempt to resolve this issue.
In my case I had to do a complete re-install to get it back to working but I was lucky because I had already done a complete backup of all user data.

Comment: Well, reinstalling the system sure will fix my issue, but I can't do it at this time as it will take a very long time and I won't be able to use my laptop for at least a full day to get my system back to its previous state.

Comment: Yeah, I understand & I wasn't suggesting that had to re-install immediately. Just trying to show you that others out here are having the same problem & it is quite catastrophic.  The only option that seemed reasonable was to choose one of the other kernel versions from GRUB but for whatever reason none of those other kernels worked for me either.  Good luck, it's quite a terrible problem.

Comment: If this is a bug, your best option is to file a bug report. Developers can't fix issues they don't know about and/or don't have enough information about. In the meantime, search for instructions on how to downgrade any problematic package.

Comment: I've found the issue, it was related to missing kernel headers, I guess that an update screwed some stuff up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I"VE FOUND THE ISSUE and was able to resolve it. I will write what I did in a non-professional way since I have barely any idea about what I've done.

For some reason, the kernel headers were missing (don't know what this is actually), so dkms wasn't able to install the graphics drivers.

I found that out by running `dkms status` and the output was something like this:

```
$ dkms status
<some other modules, kernel versions and stuff>
nvidia/520.56.06 : added
```

From this I recognized that the drivers weren't loaded, so I ran the following line:

```
$ sudo dkms autoinstall
```

And it wasn't working, it was complaining something about missing this kernel header `linux-headers-5.17.0-1020-oem`, so I installed it using apt

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-5.17.0-1020-oem
```

Then when installing it I noticed that dkms started signing some `.ko` files, then I restarted and found that my GPU drivers are finally working. I checked by writing `dkms status` again and opened `NVIDIA X-Server Settings` and found the usual settings are back.