# 22.10 Nouveau drivers not working - emergency mode

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.10

## Hardware Context

- Nvidia GeForce 960
- Intel i9 11900K
- ASUS TUF GAMING B60M-PLUS

(I think that the only relevant spec is GPU)

## Problem

Hi. I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10. A few days passed without major problems, but today I booted into Ubuntu (have dual boot with Windows 11, which is working without any problem) and ended up in emergency mode with following message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 1484190/15171584 files, 18827904/60659968 blocks
[     3.712179] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2L Unable to configura, disabling
[     3.712285] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 80000140 FAULT at 10eb14
 [ PRIVRING ]
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

#### First try

After some googling I decided to blacklist nouveau drivers adding to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then running `update-initramfs -u` and `reboot`.

---

Message changed to the following but still not booting into graphic desktop. Fun fact is that font changed to a more stylized one, I think that Ubuntu's terminal default font.

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 1484190/15171584 files, 18827904/60659968 blocks
[     3.590755] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2L Unable to configure, disabling
[     5.156330] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter formaintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

After that, I tried to install nvidia propietary drivers from ubuntu repositories doing `apt-get install nvidia-drivers-515`, but at the end of the installation, terminal freezes for say 2 minutes and then prompts again with "emergency mode". Nvidia drivers are not installed: `dpkg -l` shows nothing about nvidia and I can run `apt-get install nvidia-drivers-515` again with the exact same result. The same happens with any `apt-get` or `apt` command, even `update`. This already happened before blacklisting nouveau.

I've downloaded drivers from Nvidia site, but I don't know if use it, because when I run it, it shows a warning which says that is better to use distribution packages.

#### Third shot (UPDATE)

Followed Nmath suggestion and ran `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` which installed nvidia drivers. After reboot, I still get into emergency mode, but with a slightly different message: no Bluetooth fail.

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 1484190/15171584 files, 18827904/60659968 blocks
[     3.602462] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2L Unable to configure, disabling
[     3.672505] 
You are in emergency mode.
```

Note the blank line under `hdaudio` and befor "Emergency mode" prompt.

Comment: That was a quick response, thank you so much. Unfortunately, it didn't work. After running `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (which installed nvidia drivers as `dpkg -l` shows), I rebooted but still enters into emergency mode. I updated my post which this new shot.

Comment: NVidia drivers seem to be causing problems all of a sudden. 
I've had a lot of issues with it in past few days.  Check this out, I figured out that you can choose the 470 driver from Updates & Settings: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix/1437456#1437456

Comment: Thank you, raddevus. But i can't access Updates & Settings AFAIK I'm unable to boot in GUI mode, just emergency mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `/boot/efi` entry in `/etc/fstab`, it was broken, maybe some upgrade messed it up. I don't know if nouveau drivers were the problem at the begining or I was just missleading. Closing this.

Comment: Just an FYI for you questions and answers stay forever they never get closed. Someone may benefit from it in the future.