# I lost my Desktop after regular updated my Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, .desktop

My Ubuntu 22.04 was regular updated again and after reboot I lost my Desktop. I get just a black screen and a `login` string. When I enter a `name`, the `Password` appears. Then I enter the `password` and just get into the `terminal`.

I tried to install the `ubuntu-desktop` through the `Terminal`, it doesn’t work, some files are missing or something is in the way. I've tried `reinstall ubuntu-desktop` - and I get the same thing.

I've tried reinstalling the `Nvidia` drivers but still getting errors.

Any advice and help on restoring the Desktop is welcome.

Comment: Can you please post what commands you have tried and any errors you have received.

Comment: @David `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: You said you did something with the Nvidia drivers as well.

Comment: You can read this website. It is in Spanish, but you can use Google Translate. http://www.edulibre.info/una-solucion-a-la-pantalla-negra

Comment: Very similar to issues I encountered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen and had to uninstall the GPU driver to get back to a working desktop.

Also have you tried startx at the command prompt?